# ¿Cómo saber hasta qué punto normalizar una base de datos?

Tags: base-de-datos, teoría

¿Cómo podría saber hasta qué punto debo normalizar una base de datos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como menciona user227, siempre se ha recomendado llegar al menos hasta la tercera forma normal, pero yo siempre le siempre sugiero normalizar hasta el punto donde el costo de implementar las formas normales sea superior al beneficio de que esté normalizada la base de datos.

Es decir, en una base de datos nueva, entonces si puede ser útil llegar a la tercera, cuarta o quinta forma normal (por que el costo es mínimo, apenas estás diseñando); pero en una base de datos que ya está en producción y que almacena muchas tablas con muchos registros entonces quizá el costo sea muy alto y no vale la pena cambiar toda la estructura.

Las formas normales son sugerencias -muy buenas sugerencias, eso si- pero no son leyes inquebrantables.

Answer (score 6):

Puesto que hablas de [normalización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalizaci%C3%B3n_de_bases_de_datos), tu pregunta apunta a bases de datos entidad-relación o relacionales, que apuntan a sistemas transacciones en línea, también conocidos como OLTP (OnLine Transaction Processing).

En estos sistemas, lo común es que las bases de datos se normalicen hasta la [tercera forma normal](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercera_forma_normal). Para ello, es importante revisar las condiciones de la primera, segunda y tercera forma normal.

### Primera forma normal ([fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primera_forma_normal#Las_tablas_1FN_como_representaciones_de_relaciones))

> 1. No hay orden de arriba-a-abajo en las filas.
> 2. No hay orden de izquierda-a-derecha en las columnas.
> 3. No hay filas duplicadas.
> 4. Cada intersección de fila-y-columna contiene exactamente un valor del dominio aplicable (y nada más).
> 5. Todas las columnas son regulares [es decir, las filas no tienen componentes como IDs de fila, IDs de objeto, o timestamps ocultos].

### Segunda forma normal ([fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segunda_forma_normal))

> una tabla 1NF está en 2NF si y solo si, dada una clave primaria y cualquier atributo que no sea un constituyente de la clave primaria, el atributo no clave depende de toda la clave primaria en vez de solo de una parte de ella

### Tercera forma normal ([fuente](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tercera_forma_normal)

> - La tabla está en la segunda forma normal (2NF)
> - Ningún atributo no-primario de la tabla es dependiente transitivamente de una clave primaria
> - Es una relación que no incluye ningún atributo clave

Existen más formas normales adicionales, que son la forma normal de Boyce-Codd, la cuarta forma normal y la quinta forma normal, pero en la práctica, al llegar a la quinta forma normal el resultado es similar (a veces el mismo) que el obtenido de la tercera forma normal.

Puedes revisar [el paper de E. F. Codd sobre normalización](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~zives/03f/cis550/codd.pdf) donde se cubren estos puntos con mayor detalle.