# Error al crear Foreign Key en MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql

Tengo una tabla llamada "mantenimiento_eventos" y otra llamada "mantenimiento_invitaciones". Ambas tablas tienen una columna llamada "fecha" de tipo "DATE" y NN.

Al crear el Foreign Key entre estas columnas recibo el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla "mantenimiento_invitaciones":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tabla "mantenimiento_eventos":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me deja seleccionar ninguna columna de referencia y si lo hago me da error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cuál podría ser el error, cómo puedo arreglar esto?.

Comment: Poniendo el error de lado, ¿estás seguro de que tiene sentido crear la clave foránea for la columna fecha? Eso es muy inusual.

Comment: pues, la idea era, al crear una invitacion, esta debe tener un nombre, el evento (nombre de un evento creado), y por ultimo la fecha del evento (la fecha del evento creado). Tengo otra clave foránea para los invitados (nombre del invitado de mi tabla invitados) La idea es que estos datos me los hale automáticamente. Creo una invitacion nueva, eligo usuarios, selecciono el evento, y la fecha se copie automatico. no es buena idea?. por qué quería seleccionar una fecha distinta a la fecha del evento?.

Comment: La respuesta de Luiggi cubre muy bien el punto que quería comunicar.

Comment: Si estás aprendiendo, te recomiendo evitar usar las herramientas que generan el código por ti. Lo mejor es ensuciarte las manos y aprender de verdad.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza estoy aprendiendo todavía y no uso ninguna herramienta para generar código. Trato de hacer todo yo mismo, pidiendo consejos y preguntando. Lo único que me ha dado mas trabajo es el diseño de la base de datos, es mi primera vez y el tema de claves foráneas, uno a muchos, uno a uno, etc.. es algo confuso para mí en estos momentos. La idea era que al crear una invitación, se seleccione uno de los eventos ya creados, y la fecha de la invitación la hale automático, ya que no tiene sentido invitar a una persona a un evento con una fecha errónea.

Comment: Lo decía porque usas la herramienta MySQL Workbench para: crear las tablas, crear las llaves foráneas, mostrarnos las estructuras de tus tablas. Puedes ejecutar el query `SHOW CREATE TABLE <nombre_tabla>` para que el motor muestre el DDL (código SQL) que permite ver cómo se creó tu tabla.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah vale, si, he estado usando workbench, pensé que todo el mundo lo hacía con esta herramienta. He eliminado "mantenimiento_" de las tablas y la fecha de la tabla "invitaciones", es cierto que la fecha puedo buscarla por el "nombre" del evento y mostrarla. Otra cosa, no uso ID para nada, todos los PK son el "nombre", debería reemplazar esto por ID tipo AI?. Excúsame por las preguntas tontas, soy nuevo y trato de entender todo y aprenderlo realmente. Screenshot: http://oi66.tinypic.com/11qn6sx.jpg

Comment: Al usar llaves primarias sobre columnas numéricas es más sencillo y ocupa menos espacio que al usar llaves primarias sobre columnas tipo varchar. Además, resulta más sencillo usar este tipo de llaves con tablas que pueden crecer mucho en datos respecto a tablas que crecen muy lentamente y son principalmente para guardar configuraciones. Este tipo de cosas se revisan en cursos de bases de datos.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza por alguna razón me han puesto a realizar este programa y no nos han dado base de datos, se puede decir que he aprendido por mí mismo gracias  Google, ya que el profesor es un cero a la izquierda. Aunque sea solo una asignación rápida, no es tratar de que funcione y ya, trato de hacerlo correctamente para obtener el conocimiento y saber el por qué de las cosas.

Comment: Así pasa a veces, no queda más que ser auto didacta. Espero que te ayudemos a resolver tus problemas y también con el uso de buenas prácticas :D

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza muchas gracias hermano. Estoy agregandole ID AutoIncrement a todo y asignarle PK, en lugar del "nombre" como PK. si no te molesta, me gustaría hacerte una pregunta sobre Invitaciones, en la BD solo debo guardar entonces, ID, nombre de la invitacion, invitados y el evento, todos con ID y claves foráneas a mi tabla invitados y eventos?.

Comment: Te recomiendo revisar sobre [normalización de base de datos](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/19877/227).

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza vale, lo he leído, ahora estoy viendo este video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bO18omSzeR4, me ha servido de mucho, ahora puedo organizar un poco mejor la BD, gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En MySQL las llaves foráneas solo se pueden aplicar haciendo referencia a una columna que tenga un índice asociado, tal como se explica en [la documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html).

Por ejemplo, revisemos este script:

```sql
-- Creamos una tabla T1 (padre)
CREATE TABLE t1(
campo1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
fecha DATE NOT NULL);

-- Creamos una tabla T2 (hija)
CREATE TABLE t2(
campo2 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
fecha DATE NOT NULL,
fechaT1 DATE NOT NULL -- intentaremos referenciar la fecha de T1
);

-- Intentamos crear una llave foránea en t2
-- sobre la columna fechaT1
-- que se asocie a la columna FECHA de la tabla T1.
-- Esto va a fallar.
ALTER TABLE t2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (fechaT1) REFERENCES t1(fecha);

-- Alteramos la tabla T1
-- para crear un índice sobre la columna FECHA
ALTER TABLE t1
ADD INDEX (fecha);

-- Ahora que existe un índice sobre T1.FECHA
-- intentaremos recrear la llave foránea en T2.
-- Esto va a funcionar
ALTER TABLE t2
ADD FOREIGN KEY (fechaT1) REFERENCES t1(fecha);
```

Entonces, la solución **parece ser** que solo deberías crear un índice sobre el campo que requieres.

**OJO**. La solución real **NO ES** la que indico arriba. Técnicamente, resolverá el problema, pero es un **mal diseño de base de datos**. Lo que deberías hacer es crear verdaderas llaves primarias para ambas tablas basadas en un ID numérico y asociar las tablas por sus llaves primarias. En script, esto sería:

```
-- el prefijo mantenimiento_ no aplica en aplicaciones del mundo real

CREATE TABLE evento (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nombre VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    fecha DATE NOT NULL,
    ubicacion VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
    tipo VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

-- La columna "nombre" no tiene mucho sentido porque lo que necesitas
-- es el nombre del invitado.
-- "fecha" tampoco tiene sentido porque la fecha de la invitación
-- es en realidad la fecha del evento
-- a menos que tu intención sea indicar la fecha de entrega
-- de la invitación
-- de ser así, sería mejor colocar un nombre más apropiado
-- para esa columna
CREATE TABLE invitacion (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    invitado VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    -- El id del evento como columna que nos permitirá
    -- crear la referencia mediante una llave foránea
    id_evento INT NOT NULL,
    -- La llave foránea que define la relación entre las tablas
    -- evento (padre) e invitacion (hija)
    FOREIGN KEY (id_evento) REFERENCES evento(id)
);
```